# Golang http client failing with: dial tcp <some ip>: connect: operation timed out

Tags: go

I have a program in Go which takes around 10k urls (**same base url**, simply different resource) and request response for them from 10k goroutines.

At some point, I start receiving :

```
Get "https://.....": dial tcp <some_ip>: connect: operation timed out
```

I can't understand whether that's due to some Go limitation, my local machine (macbook) limitation, or the limitations of the Server(s).
And how can it be solved.

My code is simple :

```
var transport = &http.Transport{
    TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true},
    Dial: (&net.Dialer{
        Timeout:   0,
        KeepAlive: 0,
    }).Dial,
    TLSHandshakeTimeout: 10 * time.Second,
}
var httpClient = &http.Client{Transport: transport}


func main() {
   for id := 1; id <= total; id++ {
       myWaitGroup.Add(1)
       go checkUri(myBaseUrl, id, some_chan)
   }

   myWaitGroup.Wait()
}


func checkUri(baseUrl string, id int, myChan string) {
    defer myWaitGroup.Done()

    url := fmt.Sprintf(`%s/%d.json`, baseUrl, id)

    req, _ := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, url, nil)
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    req.Header.Set("Connection", "close")
    response, err := httpClient.Do(req)
    
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("ERROR: http remote call, err:", err)
        return
    } else {
        defer response.Body.Close()
        if response.StatusCode != 200 {
            fmt.Printf("ERROR: remote call status code %d [%s]\n", response.StatusCode, url)
            return
        } else {
           .. io.ReadAll(response.Body)
           myChan <- fmt.Sprintf(string(b))
           ..
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: a net timeout error means that the program was not able to read data from the socket in time. Out of that fact it is hard, without further observation results, to understand the root cause. It could be a bandwidth issue, a remote that is unavailable, a soft (kernel/app) limit, a network downtime. Though, you are spinning 10K // requests, it is very likely that you will increase the success rate if you were more gentle and limited that to some upper bound concurrency limit n accordance with your hardware capabilities.

Comment: @mh-cbon do you have any idea how to limit the max concurrent goroutines?
I found for example, that with 300 goroutines it works well. (isn't it too low btw?)
So how can I take 10k, and say "at any given time, do 300, until you're done with all the 10k" ?

Comment: @mh-cbon I tried setting MaxConnsPerHost in transport to 40, and there were almost no errors this time. However, it's very slow, takes me almost 10 minutes to finish. Is there anything that be configured to balance failures and performance?

Comment: You're literally trying to make 10K outgoing calls simultaneously.  There's no way your OS/network can keep up (or your CPU in all likelihood).  You have maybe 8-24 actual system threads being split 10,000 ways - some of those are going to starve while others are serviced.  You can trivially park on incoming connections -- but outgoing is self-initiated, and all of those try to compete simultaneously.  Never gonna work like that.

Comment: One idea would be to make a single queue for all of the work - and then build N goroutines to pull from that queue (channel).  Limit N to whatever you system can handle simultaneously - say 40 - and let them keep pulling from the channel until you exhaust the jobs.

Comment: I tried to make only (maximum) 40 goroutines at any given time, but it's just really slow, it takes 7.7 minutes to complete everything.

Unfortunately I am not expert in the network field, so thanks for explaining the problem. 
What can be done to achieve making those 10k requests in minimal time (less than a minute) ?
Will it force me to deploy multiple microservice instances and have each of them do a certain chunk of those requests and then somehow combine all of their results ?

Comment: Keep in mind, that the server that you are querying may not be able to respond to 10k requests in a minute. It's almost 167 requests per second. The option proposed by @Mordachai is the working one. You can make the number of goroutines configurable, increase it and see whether the server responds without timeouts.